# How to use crittercism with apportable?

Tags: android, objective-c, apportable, crittercism

I am porting my iOS game to Android using Apportable and just ran into an issue with Crittercism that I haven't been able to solve.

First of all I noticed that the Apportable SDK comes with an old version of Crittercism embedded (3.0.2), that version is really old and I would rather not use it. Also it was impossible for me to link against it previously because whenever I tried to write a wrapper for it the java compiler would complain that the Crittercism package didn't exist (that has been fixed in the latest Apportable SDK version 1.1.06).

What I ended up doing is writing a dummy jar which I used to replace the embedded Crittercism jar in the SDK folder, then linked against the newest Crittercism jar from their website and wrote a simple wrapper to pass the application context to it. This results in Crittercism initializing properly and reporting app loads properly but it fails to report crashes.

Using the new Apportable SDK I have tried the old embedded version of Crittercism to no avail, the same problem persists, app loads are reported properly but app crashes are not reported at all. I also found [this article](http://support.crittercism.com/customer/portal/articles/662549-i-can-see-app-loads-but-no-crashes-what-is-going-wrong-) in the Crittercism website that explains that the library won't report crashes if there's anything else catching exceptions before it does.

So here are my questions:

Why is there an embedded Crittecism jar in the apportable SDK?
Is there a better way to use Crittercism with my Apportable app?
Can I use the newest Crittercism library with Apportable?
Is there anything else catching exceptions in the Apportable runtime?
If Crittercism won't work with my app, are there any other working options?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: you should take this to Apportable directly

Comment: @LearnCocos2D is right. It sounds like maybe Apportable is already using Crittercism to monitor the performance of their SDK. (Are you able to set a Crittercism App ID for the Crittercism library that's included by default, 3.0.2?)  It's also possible that Apportable uses their own global uncaughtExceptionHandler. Either of these scenarios would prevent you from getting crashes inside Crittercism.

Comment: Yeah, you both are right, I sent Apportable an e-mail, I'll report here when they get back to me, just in case anyone runs into this problem in the future. @JeremiahEdwards yes, I was able to initialize the default 3.0.2 version of Crittercism properly using my app keys but it only reported app loads and not crashes.

Comment: So I sent apportable an e-mail to sdk [at] apportable [dot] com over one week ago and they haven't replied yet. If they ever respond I'll update this question. I guess the answer for now is "do not use crittercism", we've moved to crashlytics and at least things are working.